# Keras Sub classing api style

Tags: python, api, tensorflow, keras, subclass

I'm stuck to make a model with a subclass method.The question is that in this subclass method where is our input shape method and where is our compilation step?

Kindly help I have to do my assignments.

```
import tensorflow as tf

class MyModel(tf.keras.Model):

  def __init__(self):
    self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation=tf.nn.softmax)

  def call(self, inputs):
    x = self.dense1(inputs)
    return self.dense2(x)

model = MyModel()
```

Here is [the link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model)

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling the ancestor's constructor in `__init__`? I don't know what you mean by *where is the compilation step*. Python compiles when you run the program.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this code taken from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras can help:

```
class MyModel(keras.Model):

  def __init__(self, num_classes=10):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__(name='my_model')
    self.num_classes = num_classes
    # Define your layers here.
    self.dense_1 = keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu')
    self.dense_2 = keras.layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='sigmoid')

  def call(self, inputs):
    # Define your forward pass here,
    # using layers you previously defined (in `__init__`).
    x = self.dense_1(inputs)
    return self.dense_2(x)

  def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
    # You need to override this function if you want to use the subclassed model
    # as part of a functional-style model.
    # Otherwise, this method is optional.
    shape = tf.TensorShape(input_shape).as_list()
    shape[-1] = self.num_classes
    return tf.TensorShape(shape)


# Instantiates the subclassed model.
model = MyModel(num_classes=10)

# The compile step specifies the training configuration.
model.compile(optimizer=tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(0.001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# Trains for 5 epochs.
model.fit(data, labels, batch_size=32, epochs=5)
```

You can see the "model.compile" call and in the fit phase you will pass your input data to the model. How the data flows inside the model is defined inside the call method, so if you want to do some input size validation you can put it there too.

Seba

Comment: please post full link to the code snippet not just reference to Keras page